# How to get a non-square plot in R?

Tags: r

How do I get a rectangular space for a plot (so the x axis is e.g. twice as long as the y axis)??

Right now I am doing

```
plot(xValues, yValues, type="l" , cex=dotsize ,
     xlim=c(0,max_x), ylim=c(1, max_y) ,
     bty="n" )
```

I tried using pty="m" but that didn't change anything (I guess I do not really understand what it is supposed to do...).
I do not want the scales to alter, so asp is not what I mean (at least, from what I have tried so far).

So, what I have right now (though it actually a line) is:

```
|     .
|   .
| .
________
  1 2 3
```

and what I want would be somthing like:

```
|               .
|         .
|   . 
__________________
    1     2     3
```

... if that helps...

Comment: Specify it in the device (e.g., width and height in `pdf`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the plotting canvas when the device gets created, for example with `dev.new`:

```
dev.new(height=5,width=10)
plot(xValues, yValues, type="l" , cex=dotsize ,
     xlim=c(0,max_x), ylim=c(1, max_y) ,
     bty="n" )
```

Comment: Brilliant, that does it. I knew it should be something simple (spent quite some time on it though...).

Thanks!

Comment: In RStudio it is sufficient to resize the plot section. It will execute this command in background for you.

Comment: What if you're using a loop to create numerous plots with various desirable shapes that are all being created in the same device (in my case a new .pdf file)?