# r plots with unequal length of x and y axes

Tags: r, plot

I want to use r to plot data points in an area whose x and y axes are of unequal length.

Specifically, the coordinates range from -136 to 136 on the X Axes, and from 0 to 420 on the y axes.

my naive approach to create a plot that would fit the data with

```
plot(x=-136:136, y=0:420, type= "n", main="distribution", xlab='xdescr', ylab='ydescr')
```

fails with

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

(How) is it possible to create a plot that fits this data? Is it inevitable to create a plot with equal axes length?

**edit:** the plotted area itself must not be square because the values represent the same (distance) along both axes

**edit:** I tried the solution suggested here [How to get a non-square plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323292/how-to-get-a-non-square-plot-in-r). That doesn't produce a plot like I want - the result is stretched in the wrong direction (landscape-y rather than portrait-y)

Comment: I think that you are looking for `xlim` and `ylim`.   See  `?par`

Comment: `plot(NULL, xlim=c(-136, 136), ylim = c(0, 420))`

Comment: thank you, that works. I stupidly didn't immediately recognise that the displayed plot 'reflows' with its window

Answer (score 1):

With `ggplot2`, you could do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point() + 
  ylim(0, 420) +
  xlim(-136, 136) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image]

See: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html

Comment: thanks! what is the data.frame()%>% line doing in this snippet?

Comment: Kust a blank dataset, you would replace `data.frame()` with your dataset and then add `aes(x, y)` inside of `ggplot`. If you provide me a reproducible example with `dput()` I'll be happy to plot it for you.

Comment: ah, i see. for now the suggestion by headpoint works well enough, but thanks

Comment: i (only) just noticed that both the solutions suggested here compress the axis with the higher values. but that is not what the data means, 1 unit runs the same length along x and y. So the plotted area must not be square

Comment: Are you saying that the y axis should be longer because its range is larger than the x axis? The shape of the plot is just an aesthetic preference, the data will still plot correctly.

Comment: yes. i wouldn't say that the data is plotted correctly if the distances and relations are not represented on the same scale any more than a face is represented correctly if you squeeze the image to square dimensions

Comment: If using `ggplot2` add `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)`.